# How to Find out Channel_ID for telegram api?

Tags: api, telegram

In layer 40 and above Telegram has an API for fetching channel messages:

```
channels.getMessages#93d7b347 channel:InputChannel id:Vector = messages.Messages;
```

and `inputChannel` is

```
inputChannel#afeb712e channel_id:int access_hash:long = InputChannel;
```

How to find out channels `channel_id` for using in API?

Answer (score 2):

Your `channel_id` probably comes from a list of channels that you already have.

Parse through the list of channels you get from your `dialogs` result.

Comment: dialogs just returns channel_ID and for fetching message , access_hash is also required

Comment: that won't work for a channel which I am not subscribed to :(

Comment: @Samat if you are not a member of the channel/group, why should you be notified if it has messages :)